# Is there any method to get any type of sibling of a particular node in Xpath 2.0

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Is there any method to get any type of sibling of a particular node in Xpath 2.0

The axes "following-sibling" only supports for the same type of siblings.

Ex:

```
<node>
<b name="bold">abc</b>
<div>gef</div>
</node>
```

I want to select all the sibling of the `<b name="bold">`.

Comment: Shivam Agrawal, You say "Is there any method to get *any type* of sibling of a particular node in Xpath 2.0"  but then say:  "I want to select all the sibling of the `<b name="bold">`." These two statements are contradictory and as result the question has little sense if any. Please, edit the question and provide clear description of the problem and exactly what must be selected. Also, change the title of the question, if it doesn't describe the main problem and/or is misleading.

Comment: What is the type of sibling that is being missed? What XPath query did you try?

Answer (score 2):

```
Is there any method to get any type of sibling of a particular node in Xpath 2.0

The axes following-sibling only supports for the same type of siblings.
```

**Use**:

```
following-sibling::node()
```

this select all siblings nodes of any type -- elements, text-nodes, processing-instruction nodes and comment nodes.

**Here is a complete XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="/*/b[@name='bold']/following-sibling::node()">
      "<xsl:copy-of select="."/>"
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<node>
    <b name="bold">abc</b>
    <div>gef</div>
</node>
```

**the XPath expression is applied (off the wanted element) and all selected three nodes are copied to the output**:

```
      "
    "

      "<div>gef</div>"

      "
"
```

As we can see, *all* sibling nodes are selected -- a whitespace-only text node, a `div` element and another whitespace-only text node.

**Do note**: This is an XPath 1.0 expression and I don't believe XPath 2.0 adds any new feature for selecting *siblings* than what is already in XPath 1.0.

In case by "sibling" you mean something different than the meaning of "sibling" in XPath, then you must define precisely what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question, but how about:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::b]
```

That will get all previous siblings of the `<b name="bold">abc</b>` element. The `*` selects any type of element.

If you want *all* siblings:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::b or following-sibling::b]
```

And if you want to be more specific in how you select the `b` element:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::b[@name="bold"]]
```

Comment: i want to select the div tag other then this Xpath 

'//b[@name='bold']//following-sibling::div[1]'

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The xpath will select *all* siblings, not just divs.

Comment: So you want to select all `div` siblings *other* than the first following sibling? That is not what you originally asked.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of XML with other siblings, and what you want the xpath to do?